# Why was the lady in episode 4 of Death Parade sent to the void?

Tags: death-parade, death-billiards

It was clear from her memories that she had suffered immensely throughout her life; being deceived multiple times and being a victim of physical (and maybe even mental) abuse. Also, in the end after she realised that she was dead she expressed grief for her children with whom she was just starting a “new beginning” with.

Although I agree she shouldn’t have smashed the guy’s head on the death arcade,I feel this instance of “creating extreme conditions” really *created* a certain darkness that didn’t exist in her before— as stated by Chiyuki in later episodes.

Another thing that confuses me is that after her mental breakdown Decim hugs her and tells her that “she has done well”. What does that imply, if not that she was going to be reincarnated?

Comment: Decim is not a perfect, unbiased judge. He can make mistakes in his judgement. Also, IMO the point of Death Parade is for the viewer's to think and make their own judgements, which might not be same as what is shown.